# Making a CSS3 family tree IE8 compatible

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I would like to use [this great CSS3 family tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree), but I require support for IE8. The main problem seems to be the `:before` and `:after` elements that don't hide when they should, as shown in the image below. (First grand child shouldn't have a line going to the left, last one shouldn't have on going to the right.)

[image: IE8 screw things up]

I have already tried a jQuery fallback, but to no avail. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/93kefcrs/) to play with, the code is below.

```js
// Add classes for old IE
jQuery(".tree li a:only-child, .tree li:only-child").addClass("only-child");
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
 .tree li:before, .tree li:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
 .tree li.only-child:after, .tree li.only-child:before {
    display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
 .tree li.only-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
 .tree li:first-child:before, .tree li:last-child:after {
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
 .tree li:last-child:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child:after {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
 .tree ul ul:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
 .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
 .tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
    border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Borrowed from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree -->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Parent</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked for html5 polyfills that might assist?

Comment: @charlietfl I have. HTML5 doesn't seem to be the problem, though CSS3 might have been because the `only-child` isn't supported in IE8. I solved that by adding a class in jQuery, but the problem still isn't solved.

Comment: right, the polyfills are to try to mimic same thing in older browsers  https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: @charlietfl I know what polyfills do. They don't help in this particular case. First carefully read the question before commenting, or be more specific as to what you mean. Simply posting a link to an endless page isn't really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue causing the extra borders is that unlike [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-class is not available in IE8 and below. The presence of this unrecognized selector invalidates the entire rule, causing IE to drop the following rules.

```
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li:last-child:after {
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

To fix this, you can employ your same jQuery `addClass` tactic for these elements.

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(".tree li:last-child").addClass("last-child");
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li.last-child:after {
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li.last-child:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

### Screenshot in IE8:

[image]

### Working Example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvwdxjea/)):

```js
$(window).load(function(){
// Add classes for old IE
 jQuery(".tree li a:only-child, .tree li:only-child").addClass("only-child");
 jQuery(".tree li:last-child").addClass("last-child");

});
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
 .tree li:before, .tree li:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
 .tree li.only-child:after, .tree li.only-child:before {
    display: none;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
 .tree li.only-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child:before, .tree li.last-child:after {
    border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
 .tree li.last-child:before {
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child:after {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
 .tree ul ul:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.tree li a {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/

/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
 .tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
    background: #c8e4f8;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
 .tree li a:hover+ul li::after, .tree li a:hover+ul li::before, .tree li a:hover+ul::before, .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
    border-color: #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>


<!-- Borrowed from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree -->
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="only-child"> <a href="#">Parent</a>

            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li class="only-child"> <a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li> <a class="only-child" href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="only-child" href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How did I not know this?! I always figured that "Oh hey, if it supports one, it'll support the other." Stupid me. Stupid IE! Thanks for the heads-up anyway! :)